# respond_with all the associations in Rail

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails as backend in my application. Using `respond_with` to return `show` action for `Activity` and `Workout` model.

Relationship:

```
Activity has_many Workouts
Workout has_many Exercises
... belongs_to ...
```

Controller for WorkOut:

```
def show
    respond_with Workout.find(params[:id])
end
```

Controller for Activity:

```
def show
    respond_with Activity.find(params[:id])
end
```

Route:

```
               exercises GET    /exercises(.:format)                            exercises#index
                     POST   /exercises(.:format)                            exercises#create
            exercise GET    /exercises/:id(.:format)                        exercises#show
   activity_workouts GET    /activities/:activity_id/workouts(.:format)     workouts#index
                     POST   /activities/:activity_id/workouts(.:format)     workouts#create
    activity_workout GET    /activities/:activity_id/workouts/:id(.:format) workouts#show
          activities GET    /activities(.:format)                           activities#index
                     POST   /activities(.:format)                           activities#create
            activity GET    /activities/:id(.:format)                       activities#show
```

In browser, I type in the following:

```
http://localhost:3000/activities/1.json
```

I get this, which include all the `Workouts` under this activity 1:

```
{"id":1,"title":"Climbing","description":"climbing 1","created_at":"2017-03-13T17:48:30.220Z","updated_at":"2017-03-13T17:48:30.220Z","user_id":1,"workouts":[{"id":1,"name":"workout 1","description":"workout2","activity_id":1,"created_at":"2017-03-13T17:59:45.742Z","updated_at":"2017-03-13T17:59:45.742Z"},{"id":2,"name":"workout 2","description":"description 2","activity_id":1,"created_at":"2017-03-13T19:27:57.601Z","updated_at":"2017-03-13T19:27:57.601Z"},{"id":3,"name":"workout 3","description":"description 3","activity_id":1,"created_at":"2017-03-13T20:53:53.191Z","updated_at":"2017-03-13T20:53:53.191Z"},{"id":4,"name":"workout 4","description":"des 4","activity_id":1,"created_at":"2017-03-13T20:55:15.965Z","updated_at":"2017-03-13T20:55:15.965Z"}]}
```

But when I type in:

```
http://localhost:3000/activities/1/workouts/1.json
```

I just get this **without** its `exercises` in it:

```
{"id":1,"name":"workout 1","description":"workout2","activity_id":1,"created_at":"2017-03-13T17:59:45.742Z","updated_at":"2017-03-13T17:59:45.742Z"}
```

I cannot tell what is the difference between these two actions.

**Solution:**

Add this in under model.rb

```
  def as_json(options = {})
    super(options.merge(include: :exercises))
  end
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the first, you are asking for just one specific Activity - the `Activity` with id 1 (which happens to also have a full set of `Workouts attached to it).

In the second action you have asked for one specific workout by id. The `Workout` with the id of `1` - which is what you are receiving in the json

It's doing exactly what you asked for...  ;)

Comment: There should be `exercies` under workout, but they are not showing

Comment: ^^ This should be part of your original question (it wasn't obvious what you thought was wrong about the two different actions).

Comment: Do you have an `includes` somewhere for your `Activity` model? It's *plausible* that Rails is inferring the nested structure for an `Activity`->`Workout` based on the given nested routes (which is not present for `Workout` ->`Exercise`)... not including associations is the Rails Standard... so to add in `Exercise` you will need to add an `includes` statement

Comment: `def as_json(options = {})
     super(options.merge(include: :exercises))
   end ` this solves it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is what I need to get all the associations under each model. I guess without it, each model will just show up without it. Thanks for the help though!

```
  def as_json(options = {})
    super(options.merge(include: :exercises))
  end
```